# How to document Typescript type in Storybook

Tags: typescript, storybook

I have this TypeScript type:

```
export type AnalyticsEventMap = {
    event1: { prop1: string },
    event2: { prop1: number, prop2: string },
}
```

How can I import it in a Storybook 7 file and iterate through its keys and values?

I want to output HTML like this in Storybook:

```
<div>
   <h1>event1</h1>
   <p>prop1: string</p>
   <h1>event2</h1>
   <p>prop1: number, prop2: string </p>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to iterate through the type or the object? because types don't exist at runtime. if you want to iterate over the object, `Object.keys` is what you are looking for